# Unable to access private and public members from friend class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, most-vexing-parse

I have a class called locationdata which has a friend class called PointTwoD

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class locationdata
{
  public:
  locationdata(); //default constructor
  locationdata(string,int,int,float,float); //constructor

 //setter
 void set_sunType(string);
 void set_noOfEarthLikePlanets(int);
 void set_noOfEarthLikeMoons(int);
 void set_aveParticulateDensity(float);
 void set_avePlasmaDensity(float);

 //getter 
 string get_sunType();
 int get_noOfEarthLikePlanets();
 int get_noOfEarthLikeMoons();
 float get_aveParticulateDensity();
 float get_avePlasmaDensity();


 float computeCivIndex();
 friend class PointTwoD;  //friend class

  private:

  string sunType;
  int noOfEarthLikePlanets;
  int noOfEarthLikeMoons;
  float aveParticulateDensity;
  float avePlasmaDensity;

};
```

I have another class called PointTwoD which is suppose to contain the class: locationdata as a private member .

```
#include <iostream>
#include "locationdata.h"

using namespace std;

class PointTwoD
{
  public:
  PointTwoD();
  locationdata location; // class


  private:
  int x;
  int y;

  float civIndex;
```

};

When i try to instantiate a PointTwoD object in my main() , and use the functions fromn locationdata , i get a error : request for member 'location' in "test" which is of non class type PointTwoD()().

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PointTwoD.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int choice;

   PointTwoD test();

    cout<<test.location->get_sunType; //this causes the error
}
```

My questions is

1) Why doesnt my friend class work , i thought i should be able to access all properties use all functions from friend once it has been declared

2) Should i use inheritance instead of friend class to access all the method and properties of class locationdata from class PointTwoD ??

First UPDATE : After i changed declaration from PointTwoD test() to PointTwoD test , i get the following error : base operand of '->' has non-pointer type , what does it mean and how to solve it

Comment: The most vexxing parse strikes again.

Comment: As the new error says, its a non-pointer type, use `.` operator instead of `->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here:

`PointTwoD test();`

is a function declaration, not a variable definition.

You need:

`PointTwoD test;`

or in C++11:

`PointTwoD test{};`

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse for more info.

Comment: A new error means a new question. As this question as about the error we've already fixed. You should also try debugging the new error yourself now that the old one is fixed before seeking assistance.